# Добавить до определенного слова в строке другое слово, если такая связка уже есть - ничего не делать

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строчки, которые имеют вид:

```
"This text will be generated using My App", "Something from App will be generated".
```

Нужно взять строку и везде где есть слово `"App"`, добавить к нему слово `"My"`. А там где уже есть сочетание `"My App"` - ничего не делать.

Я реализовал это с помощью `.Split()` и перебора значений со сравнением `current - 1` элемента.

Как можно это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!\bMy\s+)App\b", "My $&");
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5CbMy%5Cs%2B%29App%5Cb&i=This%20text%20will%20be%20generated%20using%20My%20App%22%2C%20%22Something%20from%20App%20will%20be%20generated&r=My%20%24%26).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\bMy\s+)` - блок негативного просмотра назад, который исключает совпадение последующих шаблонов, если непосредственно перед текущей позицией есть совпадение

  - `\b` - граница слова
  - `My` - буквальная подстрока
  - `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `App` - буквальная подстрока
- `\b` - граница слова.

В шаблоне замены `$&` возвращает значение целого совпадения.